# Implementing older version of mySQL on RH9

Tags: mysql, redhat, mysql-3

I'm building a virtual machine running Red Hat Linux 9 (Shrike) and MySQL. This is to virtualize a current production system that needs new hardware.  Questions:

1. Can I copy the existing mysql daemon executables to the new machine from the old one and if so, where are they located, and what is involved?
2. Are their archived packages of the early mySQL packages? I was hoping to find the exact version running on my old server, to do an install, and the copy the database file.

#### Update:

Hi..... many thanks for the ideas.  I'm pretty sure the copy is the way to go.... (thanks Tometzky), but it is somewhat fraught, as the old hardware has a software RAID array, so I'm not sure I can do a bitcopy and have it work. And, the original mySQL is 3.23 (just about the first production version....). Earliest source I've found was at SkyServer which started at version 4.x.

A dd from one /dev/sda to /dev/sdb seems to work fine (simulated in VirtualBox).  So far an /dev/md0 (from a RAID 1 drive) doesn't work....but I'm going to try copying partitions individually, and then see if that will work.

Our original mySQL is 3.23 (just about the first production version....). Earliest packaged binaries at SkyServer are 4.1

Obviously, this is a temporary move to buy us some time while we re-write the applications that query the mySQL.

Comment: What is the exact version of MySQL you want to install ??? Run `SELECT VERSION();` in the mysql client or run `mysql --version` at the Linux command line.

Comment: Why don't you just copy old system hard drive to new system virtual hard drive and declare it done? If you don't move to a modern, supported distribution, then there's no benefit in reinstalling anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not risk moving the installed binaries laterally to a newer OS because you may have to drag along needed libraries WHICH MAY NOT WORK IN THE NEWER OS !!!

You should thoroughly [look through MySQL's Archives](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/), which goes back to MySQL 5.0.15.

SkySQL also tries to fully accommodate users of [older versions of MySQL, MariaDB, and more](http://www.skysql.com/downloads/). Please go to [their repository and find the version you need](http://downloads.skysql.com/archive/index/p/mysql). They go back to MySQL 4.1.

You should make sure SkySQL has RHEL6 builds, at least.

You could also try compiling MySQL from source within RH9. **DISCLAIMER : Never Built MySQL From Source**

Comment: Okay, @RolandoMySQLDBA, I'll bite.  Why "never?"  I would agree that official binaries are ideal, and I'll agree that it isn't ideal to compile your own, since you could be compiling against libraries that introduce vulnerabilities, like the big one a couple of years ago where a bad password would successfully log in if you tried it enough times... but the lesson I took away from that includes not running Linux-disto-provided MySQL either, since they generally compile from source, too (afaik).  Is that why you say "never" -- potential instability or vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I think the "never" means that Rolando has never personally built MySQL from source.

Comment: @ypercube on reflection, I think you are probably right.  I may have misread "built" as "build" as though it were advice on what not do to, rather than what he hasn't personally tried.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would point out is that MySQL data files are quite portable.  You don't have to worry about endianess/bitness/operating system etc.

The next thing to mention, is that in MySQL versions do not always paint a picture of what has changed:

- There is more code changed/introduced between 5.5 and 5.6 than any prior version.
- The difference in 4.1 and above is quite large with the introduction of character-sets.
- Since I assume this is for a legacy environment you are not able to change much, I would really recommend trying to find a version no more recent than MySQL 4.0.

I can't vouch for their credibility, but I did manage to find 4.0 RPMs with a Google search for "mysql 4.0 rpm".  The obligatory disclaimer of course is that MySQL 5.5 is now the minimum supported version of MySQL.  But that will be the same case with using Red Hat Linux 9 (Shrike).